# Submit button inside JQM popup not hitting action method in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-mobile, razor

My issue is that submit button which is placed inside Jquery Mobile popup and enclosed in Form Razor, when clicked, not hitting the Controller Action.

Find my code below:

**Anchor tag** which invokes div popup

```
<a data-role="none" data-theme="none" data-corners="false" style="text-decoration:none;" data-shadow="false" data-rel="popup" data-inline="true" href="#dvMPPopup" id="ancPopup_@i" class="ancQtyPopup">
```

**The Div Popup**

```
      @using (Html.BeginForm("AdjustQuantity", "ManualPickingSearch", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "formAdjustQty" , data_ajax="false"}))
    {
    <div data-role="popup" data-position-to="window" data-theme="a" class="ui-content" id="dvDPPopup">
    <div class="ui-grid-d" style="text-align: center; padding-left: 5%">
        <div class="ui-block-a" style="width: 15%; padding-left: 3%">
            <div class="HwySearchlblStyle">Qty Picked</div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-b" style="padding-left: 1%; width: 7%">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.PKQLTM, new { data_corners = "false", id = "txtDPPkd" })
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-c" style="padding-left: 10%; width: 23%">
            <div class="HwySearchlblStyle">Process Password</div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-d" style="padding-left: 5%; width: auto">
            <div>@Html.PasswordFor(Model => Model.Password, new { data_corners = "false" })</div>
        </div>

        <div class="ui-block-e" style="padding-left: 1%;">
            **<input type="submit" id="btnDpadjQty" name="btnpopups" class="HwyTaskIcon" data-role="none" value="" />**
        </div>
        <div id="errorMsg"></div>
    </div>
</div>}
```

**The Controller Action Method**

```
public ActionResult AdjustQuantity(...)
        {}
```

Plase help me guys , I have to solve this issue

Comment: Where in your code is the action for the submit?!

Comment: I have input type - submit button which is 
input type="submit" id="btnDpadjQty"   so on clicking this I have a form razor around which takes me to controller

Comment: Then please post the HTML created by the ASP.

Comment: just use [HttPPost] at the top of ur post controller.

Comment: hai @RobSchmuecker : The html which I saw using IE Developer Tools does not contain form tag over div popup

Comment: Sorry I cannot help you further without you being able to understand basic HTML and/or your ASP to get it to output basic HTML.

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla: Sorry not hitting the controller action

Answer (score 1):

> Just start your form after data-role="popup". That's it.

```
<div data-role="popup" data-position-to="window" data-theme="a" class="ui-content" id="dvDPPopup">
@using (Html.BeginForm("AdjustQuantity", "ManualPickingSearch", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "formAdjustQty" , data_ajax="false"}))
{
//Your remaining code
}
</div>
```